# Issues while fetching from Core Data

Tags: ios, database, xcode, core-data, swift3

I'm facing this really weird issue for the first time in swift. i have 8 values in json. through service i'm parsing that json and saving those values in coreData. all of the 8 values are being saved. but when i fetch the value from that table. it sometimes return 4 values or 5 or 3, like randomly but not all. i'm not even applying any predicates. i'm badly stuck as i'm unable to understand the problem.

This is how i'm saving it in CoreData:

```
    for field in json as? [AnyObject] ?? [] {

     self.SaveDayViewDetails(monthlyid: (field["MonthlyID"] as! String), mioauthid: (field["MIOAuthID"] as! String), empid: (field["EmpID"] as! String), doctorid: (field["DoctorID"] as! String))

  }

class func SaveDayViewDetails (monthlyid: String, mioauthid: String, empid : String,doctorid : String,doccode : String,callplanneractivityid : String,actid : String,startdate : String,speciality : String,s3 : String,s2 : String,s1 : String,plannerid : String,p4 : String,p3 : String,p2 : String,p1 : String,mstatus : String,miostatusreason : String,miostatus : String,miodescription : String,isexecuted : String,g1 : String,end_date : String,doctorname : String,classname : String,address : String,actname : String,actfcolor : String,actbcolor : String,editable : String,planmonth : String,date:String) {
        let context = getContext()

        let privateMOC = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
        privateMOC.parent = context
        //retrieve the entity that we just created
        let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Tbl_SchedularDayView", in: context)
        let transc = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
        //set the entity values
        transc.setValue(Int32(monthlyid), forKey: "monthlyid")
        transc.setValue(mioauthid, forKey: "mioauthid")
        transc.setValue(Int32(empid), forKey: "empid")
        transc.setValue(Int32(doctorid), forKey: "doctorid")

        //save the object
        do {
            try privateMOC.save()
            context.performAndWait {
                do {
                    try context.save()
                    print("total saved Tbl_SchedularDayView in Database!")
                } catch {
                    fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
                }
            }


        } catch let error as NSError  {
            print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        } catch {

            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
```

and that's how i'm fetching it:

```
     var drname:[String] = []
   let fetchRequest1:NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>  = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Tbl_SchedularDayView") // 2nd
      do{
              let searchResults = try ServiceCalls.getContext().fetch(fetchRequest1)

               for trans in searchResults as! [NSManagedObject] {
                         drname.append(trans.value(forKey: "mioauthid") as! String)
                 }
             }catch {
               print("Error with request: \(error)")
             }

 print("total docs 1 = ",drname.count," doc names = ",drname)
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually a moc is created (lazily) and hung onto for the life of the app, in your persistent store coordinator.   Your privateMOC looks like it'll be released before (or possibly during) save.  Check its lifetime. Also since you're probably using multiple MOCs, be sure to follow CoreData concurrency rules & known effective strategies for keeping changes in sync between MOCs.

See this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/145877/core-data-tutorial-multiple-managed-object-contexts-2) for an example of managing your moc(s).

Also read Apple's doc on [CoreData concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html) if you're going to use multiple mocs.

Comment: But it is saving all the 8 values, i'm printing that part. the problem is when i fetch it.

Comment: Did you try opening the sql file to truly verify they got written, for a case when a subsequent fetch isn't fully returning the values?

Comment: No i didn't, i just confirmed it by the print statement.

Comment: Also, what moc are you using during the fetch?   ServiceCalls.getContext() returns a different moc, I presume?  Your two mocs are probably not in sync.

Comment: Actually i'm not really good at this context, can you elaborate with a code? like hoe can i sync these two moc?

Comment: So per my answer, I'd switch to using a single main thread moc that lasts for app's lifetime.  Your saves need to be on that moc.   Then you can introduce other Mocs for edits vs fetches.

Comment: See this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/145877/core-data-tutorial-multiple-managed-object-contexts-2).  See how in his first fetch example, he first does this:  let context = coreDataStack.mainContext.   That's what my point is.

Comment: I've updated my answer to cover the additional points.  Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm already using CoreData concurrency, will check the tutorial today and will update here. thankss!